# Delayed broadcast response for new SMS Retriever API

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver, android-sms

Recently we decided to start using [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request) to read OTP. 
I followed all steps and **it's working correctly**.

The problem is `BroadcastReceiver` is getting callback **after a long delay**. SMS notification is pushed by system as soon as SMS is actually received. But, receiver will get it after almost a minute.

Tested on Samsung J3 emerge. Android 6.0.1, PlayServices 14.5.81.

Did anyone faced this issue? Is there receiver priority issue or any other limitation of the API?

Comment: Hey, have you got the solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Not really a solution but after a while (after few more tests) it started working and no one is complaining. Just a quick question, is the latest PlayServices installed on your device?

Comment: Yes. latest playservices installed on device.

Comment: btw, now Its working for me also. We have changed the hash string generation strategy. we generate hash string at client side. Its woks like charm now.

Comment: yes. latest playservices installed on device.

Comment: Try few more times and see if it works. I was usually killing the app and testing on signup page that's where I faced issue. First time I noticed it quick was on change phone number page (when app was already running for more than a minute). And magically it started working after that..

Comment: Oh I just noticed your last message. Congratulations :thumb_up:

Comment: @HBB20 I'm trying to read OTP only but its only re-truing TimeOut..

Comment: Are you sure that you are using correct format and hash in SMS? Hash depends on the signing key. While debugging it uses debug signing key (unless you changed) so it's hash will be different from your release build's hash.

Comment: @AkashWankhede what do you mean "we generate hash string at client side"

Comment: @Maxim Toyberman It can be generated both at server and at client side. It is easier to generate at client side.